# Are there reasons not to use DataBindingUtil.inflate?

Tags: android-databinding

When binding a fragment to a layout the two most common ways (AFAIK) to do it is to:
`FragmentMyexampleBinding binding =  FragmentMyExampleBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)`
or
`FragmentMyexampleBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_my_example, container, false)`
So my question is, what's the advantage of doing it the first way other than the statement being shorter?
Using DataBindingUtil and passing in a layout file lets Android Studio know which layout file is related and generate a shortcut icon to the layout file, and it also allows Android Studio to quickly find all reference to the layout file if you should ever want to rename it. Is there any reason not to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for [`DataBindingUtil.inflate`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/DataBindingUtil.html#inflate(android.view.LayoutInflater,%20int,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean,%20android.databinding.DataBindingComponent)) says this

> Use this version only if layoutId is unknown in advance. Otherwise,
>   use the generated Binding's inflate method to ensure type-safe
>   inflation.

So the major advantage of the `FragmentMyExampleBinding.inflate` is the fact that you're guaranteed type safety. The `DataBindingUtil.inflate` method has to do some under the hood *"hocus pocus"* at run-time to figure out what type to return, and there's a chance that something goes wrong.

So in conclusion while there isn't any reason to not use `DataBindingUtil.inflate` there's at least one reason to use `FragmentMyExampleBinding.inflate` over `DataBindingUtil.inflate` whenever you can